# How to send AKS logs into eventhub?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

What would be the best solution to stream AKS Container logs and cluster level logs to Azure Eventhub?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/kubernetes). You need also write the code to send the logs to the eventhub via the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing the same issue, unable to forward the application logs directly to event hub. The work around is to create a rule to forward the logs to the storage account and create a rule to pick it up from storage blob and stream it real time to event hub.
Creating a job to forward logs to storage account:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs#add-action
Stream logs from storage account to event hub:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-azure-monitor-stream-logs-to-event-hub