# Monitoring Azure AKS pod logs with SignalFX w/out Log Observer

Tags: kubernetes, logging, monitoring, azure-aks, signalfx

Is there any alternative way to monitor AKS Pod logs without Log Observer? I tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143373/how-to-send-aks-logs-into-eventhub) workaround using storage account/event hub, but neither does store application logs from pods. I'm able to get application logs easily from log analytics, using this query:

```
ContainerLog
| join kind = inner KubePodInventory on $left.ContainerID == $right.CointainerID
| where Namespace == "default" and LogEntry contains "error"
| project TimeGenerated, LogEntry, ContainerName
```

but not from logs stored in storage account or event hub. Is it actually possible to monitor pod logs in signalfx w/out log observer?

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed possible to monitor AKS pod logs in signalfx without log observer. I've been sending them to Splunk Observabilty Cloud (SignalFX) using otel agent for months.

You can install the `splunk-otel-collector` helm chart and tune parameters to specify what kind of data you want to send (metrics, logs, traces). The values file can give you a rough image of the capabilities: see https://github.com/signalfx/splunk-otel-collector-chart/blob/main/helm-charts/splunk-otel-collector/values.yaml

And this is the chart's repo:
https://github.com/signalfx/splunk-otel-collector-chart

```
splunkObservability:
[...]
  logsEnabled: true
```